# Use lapply/for loop with system function for batch terminal commands

Tags: r, system, lapply

I'm starting to the terminal more on my machine and would like to create a workflow where I have greater control over more repetitive tasks.  My question is, can I use the `system` function, which takes a string and runs it through the terminal, within a loop? My hang up is looping over a string. My thought is to use the glue package, but I'm wondering if there is a base function for this or a better way than invoking an outside package?

```
library(glue)

setwd(path_to_files)
dir.create('pdf')

all_files <- list.files()

lapply(all_files, function(x){
  system('sytsunoconv -f [format] pdf  {x}.pptw')
})
```

Comment: I've answered below, but I should point out that `system('sytsunoconv -f [format] pdf  {x}.pptw')` won't work without a call to `glue`. You probably mean `system(glue('sytsunoconv -f [format] pdf  {x}.pptw'))`.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, I'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `system` within an iterative loop shouldn't be a problem. To create a vector of commands you can use base R's `paste` or `paste0`, although `glue` can be useful when dealing with more complex strings.

Creating a vector of commands is as easy as `paste("say", 1:5)`, which returns `[1] "say 1" "say 2" "say 3" "say 4" "say 5"`. You can use it in a `for` loop with `system` to run each in sequence:

```r
for (command in paste("say", 1:5)) {
    system(command)
}
```

If your on a Mac you should hear the TTS pronouncing each number.

You should be able to use the same pattern for your example, e.g.:

```r
for (command in paste0('sytsunoconv -f [format] pdf ', list.files(), ".pptw")) {
    system(command)
}
```

Note that I use `paste0` here to avoid unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: @elliot `command` is just each element of `paste("say", 1:5)` in sequence, so `"say 1" "say 2" "say 3" "say 4" "say 5"`.